# What goes into content type scope mangager from pmr2-oauth (a package in plone)

Tags: python, oauth, plone

I am trying to connect my custom api to a plone website using the pmr2.oauth provider on the plone website and using oauthV1. Everything goes smoothly from requesting a temporary key to recieving the oauth access tokens.

But when I try to access the resources I get an invalid scope. I have been told to fill in the content type scope manager in pmr2.oauth package, I have to fill a mapping for each of the following portal types to a list of permitted subpaths: Plone site, Collection, File, Folder, Manager Folder, Page, Page and subsite.

But I have no idea what to fill in here, so I hope maybe you guys can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package owner here, first off I must apologize and say I can probably document this better (sure it's documented via doctests but it can be made better)!

What you need to fill there is the view that you want to access for that particular content type.  For instance, if you wish to show the listing of all the items from within a collection you would figure out what the name of the view is (in this case, atct_topic_view).  For a standard Page it would be document_view.  That said, OAuth typically targets web-services that typically communicates via a more concise format, such as json, so it is possible for developers to develop new views specific to some existing (or custom) Plone content types and then these can be added to the mappings to be made available.

Lastly, the mappings are essentially the endpoint, plus an optional subpath which can be a wildcard.  As of writing, specifying a wildcard for custom subpaths does not imply the root parent view being available, so let's say you have a custom download view that can let user list the formats which links to subpaths within for the actual content, you might do something like this:

```
Collection:

download_feed
download_feed/*
```

Would make available the download_feed view within the Collection content type and then any subpaths within (generally made available by implementing `zope.publisher.interfaces.IPublishTraverse` for the custom view).

Alternatively you can write your own ScopeManager.  Just create a class that inherit from pmr2.oauth.scope.BaseScopeManager (or BTreeScopeManager), implement all the methods (and tests) and then register this within your code or with a zcml like this:

```
<adapter
    for="zope.annotation.interfaces.IAnnotatable
         your.app.interfaces.IAppLayer"
    factory="your.app.ScopeManager"
    provides="pmr2.oauth.interfaces.IScopeManager"
    />
```

Which should then override the default (Portal) Content Type based scope manager with your own.